# Run firebase cloud function when a key is a specific value

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var IAPVerifier = require('iap_verifier');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.verifyReceipt = functions.database.ref('/Customers/{uid}/updateReceipt')
    .onWrite(event => {
        const uid = event.params.uid;
         var receipt = event.data.val();
    (strReceipt).toString('base64');
var client = new IAPVerifier('IAP_secretkey')
client.verifyAutoRenewReceipt(receipt, true,function(valid, msg, data){
    console.log(' RECEIPT');
  if(valid) {
    console.log('VALID RECEIPT');
    console.log('msg:' + msg);
   var strData = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log('data"' + strData);
    const newReceiptRef = admin.database().ref('/Customers/{uid}/');
    newReceiptRef.update({'receiptData1': data});
     const recVerRef = admin.database().ref('/Customers/{uid}/');
    newReceiptRef.update({'updateReceipt': 0});


    // update status of payment in your system
  }else{
    console.log('INVALID RECEIPT');
     console.log('msg:' + msg);
    var strData = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log('data"' + strData);
  }
});
    });
```

This is my node js cloud function. The possible values for 'updateReceipt' are 0 and 1. Is it possible to run the cloud function only when the value is 1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to only trigger the function when a specific value is present.

I can think of two options:

1. Write the nodes to a different branch depending on the `updateReceipt` value.
2. Add an `if` to your code.

The second options is definitely the simplest:

```
exports.verifyReceipt = 
functions.database.ref('/Customers/{uid}/updateReceipt')
  .onWrite(event => {
    const uid = event.params.uid;
    var receipt = event.data.val();
    if (receipt.updateReceipt === 0) {
      var client = new IAPVerifier('IAP_secretkey')
      ...
```

Alternatively, you can keep the updated receipt in a separate branch from the new receipts. That way you can trigger a function separately for just the new receipts.